# Tricky type bounds

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a parameterized class `Interval` for the seven date-time classes in [ThreeTen's drop-in Scala reimplementation of `java.time`](https://github.com/soc/scala-java-time).  My class signature looks something like this:

```
final case class Interval[T <: Temporal with Ordered[T] with Serializable](start: T, end: T)
```

This works fine when `T` is `Instant`, `LocalTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `OffsetTime`, but fails to compile for `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` because the latter three don't inherit directly from `Ordered[T]`.  I'm having trouble coming up with the correct type signature for `Interval[T]` that works for all seven.

Can someone with more experience give me a hand?  Extra thanks if you explain the theory behind the answer!

For reference, here's the signatures of the seven date-time classes:

```
final class Instant private(private val seconds: Long, private val nanos: Int) extends TemporalAccessor with Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Ordered[Instant] with Serializable
final class LocalTime(_hour: Int, _minute: Int, _second: Int, private val nano: Int) extends TemporalAccessor with Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Ordered[LocalTime] with Serializable
final class OffsetDateTime private(private val dateTime: LocalDateTime, private val offset: ZoneOffset) extends Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Ordered[OffsetDateTime] with Serializable
final class OffsetTime(private val time: LocalTime, private val offset: ZoneOffset) extends TemporalAccessor with Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Ordered[OffsetTime] with Serializable
final class LocalDate private(private val year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) extends ChronoLocalDate with Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Serializable
final class LocalDateTime private(private val date: LocalDate, private val time: LocalTime) extends ChronoLocalDateTime[LocalDate] with Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Serializable
final class ZonedDateTime(private val dateTime: LocalDateTime, private val offset: ZoneOffset, private val zone: ZoneId) extends ChronoZonedDateTime[LocalDate] with Temporal with Serializable
```

Here's the class signatures for those last three `Chrono*` traits:

```
trait ChronoLocalDate extends Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Ordered[ChronoLocalDate]
trait ChronoLocalDateTime[D <: ChronoLocalDate] extends Temporal with TemporalAdjuster with Ordered[ChronoLocalDateTime[_]]
trait ChronoZonedDateTime[D <: ChronoLocalDate] extends Temporal with Ordered[ChronoZonedDateTime[_]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would take a slightly different approach than the one you have, and simply use implicits and a sealed type family to abstract away everything. This would also give you the opportunity to implement ordering yourself for classes that do not have one defined.

```
final case class Interval[
  T <: Temporal with Serializable
](start: T, end: T)(implicit def ordering: Ordering[T])
```

Which can be re-written as:

```
final case class Interval[
  T <: Temporal with Serializable : Ordering
](start: T, end: T)
```

You can now safely exploit the fact that Scala allows you 2 ways of manipulating order, one is the old school way of Java via inheritance, (where you would implement `Comparable`), or in the case of Scala, `Ordered`, and the other is `Ordering[T]`, which is always passed through implicit scope.

And you can do that by supplying order independent of your classes:

```
object TimeOrdering {
  implicit object ChronoLocalDateOrdering extends Ordering[ChronoLocalDate] {
    override def compare(x: ChronoLocalDate, y: ChronoLocalDate): Int = ???
  }
}
```

And so on, for every type where you require ordering.

Then you can simply do:

```
val x: ChronoLocalDate = ...
val y: ChronoLocalDate = ...
import TimeOrdering._ // to get the implicits in scope.
val interval = Interval(x, y)
```